# ThreadPoolExecutor и рекурсия

Tags: python, многопоточность, рекурсия, crawling

Нужно написать паука, который бы доставал ссылки со страницы и парсил их. Так-как обычная рекурсивная версия работает не достаточно быстро, решил использовать ThreadPoolExecutor.

Есть функция:

```
    def start(self):
    if self.concurrent_mode_workers > 0:
        print("Start concurrent spider")
        self.__executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=self.concurrent_mode_workers)
        self._concurrent_spider(self.base_uri)
        self.__executor.shutdown(wait=True)
```

Создается объект Executor-а и вызывается рекурсивная функция:

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def _concurrent_spider(self, uri: str, depth: int = 0):
    if depth <= self.depth:
        sel_crawler = self.sel_crawler.__class__(self.sel_crawler.scr)
        sel_crawler.base_auth(config.LOGIN, config.PASSWORD, self.base_uri)
        if dom := sel_crawler.get_dom(uri):
            soup = BeautifulSoup(dom, "lxml")
            dom_links = self._get_dom_links(soup)
            current_date = str(datetime.datetime.now().isoformat())
            self._parsed_uris[uri] = {
                ...
            }
            for dom_link, label in dom_links:
                if dom_link in self._parsed_uris:
                    self._parsed_uris[dom_link]["last_spider_at"] = current_date
                else:
                    self.__executor.submit(self._concurrent_spider, dom_link, depth + 1)
```

Функция передает Executor-у вызов самой себя увеличивая глубину на единицу.

Проблема в том, что при такой реализации парсится только 50 ссылок, в то время, как обычная рекурсивная функция парсит больше при одинаковом `depth`. При чем 50 ссылок парсится вне зависимости от переданного `depth`.

Понятно, что проблема в рекурсии и желании использовать потоки. Хотелось бы понять, как заставить все это работать вместе.

Comment: Чему равна переменная `self.depth`?

Comment: @RomanKonoval она задается через аргументы, любое числовое значение большее 0. По дефолту - 10

Comment: В этом коде как минимум есть модификация и чтение `self._parsed_uris` из разных потоков. Если это обычный список, никак не синхронизированный, то тут потенциальная проблема с многопоточностью. А вообще трудно сказать. Пишите в лог, все ссылки, которые парсите, в одном и другом случае и сравнивайте, где различие.

Comment: @RomanKonoval по-идеи это не должно влиять на работу функции. Максимум, что это может дать, так это беспорядочная запись в структуру, но проблема в другом(

Comment: Это как раз очень может повлиять. При несинхронизированном доступе, могут нарушиться внутренние инварианты списка (сломается он если коротко) и это приведет к такому поведению, что проверка `dom_link in self_parse_uris` всегда будет возвращать `true` и соответственно новые задачи на парсинг не будут добавляться вообще.

Comment: Зачем вам рекурсия? Сделайте очередь, кладите туда url-и для обработки и разгребайте очередь. Типичная же задача. Рекурсия не нужна.

Comment: В Яве такой код `self.__executor.shutdown(wait=True)` предотвратит добавление новых задач через `submit`, т.е. выполнятся только те, что уже успели встать в очередь. Я уверен в Питоне точно так же, косвенно это подтверждается твоим сообщением - первый вызов у тебя не через пул, ты парсишь первую страницу, создаёшь таски для найденных ссылок и потом закрываешь пул для добавления новых задач.

Comment: В cPython `dict` и `list` [потокобезопасные](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock). Но есть еще один разделяемый ресурс, про который неясно как он может повлиять на работу - `self.sel_crawler.scr`. Что это?

Comment: @RomanKonoval  булевое значение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно это происходит из за того что вы используете shutdown().
Вам нужно объявить list() и аппендить в него feature-объекты которые возвращаются при вызове submit().
А shutdown() заменить на wait() и передать ему лист с этими объектами.